# Как реализовать асинхронную функцию с Promise?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise

```
import { IExecutor } from './Executor';
import ITask from './Task';

export default async function run(executor: IExecutor, queue: AsyncIterable<ITask>, maxThreads = 0)  {
  maxThreads = Math.max(0, maxThreads);
  

  const promisesCount = [] as Promise<void>[]
  let index = maxThreads
  
// 
  for await (const task of queue) {
   
      if (!promisesCount[task.targetId]) {
        promisesCount[task.targetId] = executor.executeTask(task)
      
      }
      else {
        promisesCount[task.targetId] = promisesCount[task.targetId]!.then(() => executor.executeTask(task))
       
      }
      
      
      if (index === maxThreads) {
        
        console.log(index)
 
          await Promise.all(promisesCount)
          index = 0
          promisesCount.length = 0
          
      }
 
      index++
      
  }
  
  return Promise.all(promisesCount)
}
```

Я завалил тестовое задание, но хочу разобраться всё равно, на вырост.
Каждая отдельная задача выглядит следующим образом:

```
interface Task {
  targetId: number
  action: 'init' | 'prepare' | 'work' | 'finalize' | 'cleanup'
}
```

Использовать специальные хуки _onComplete или _onExecute нельзя, они используются для диагностики и логирования.

Есть специальный класс Executor (src/Executor.ts), который умеет исполнять одну задачу:

```
Executor.executeTask(task: Task): Promise<void>
```

В решении нельзя использовать внутреннее состояние Executor, только IExecutor.executeTask().

Надо реализовать асинхронную функцию, которая получает на вход очередь задач Iterable и максимальное кол-во одновременных "потоков" maxThreads и возвращает промис, который будет разрезолвлен, когде все задачи отработают.

```
async function run(queue: Queue, maxThreads = 0): Promise<{...}>
```

При maxThreads == 0 ограничения на кол-во одновременных "потоков" нету.

Функция должна исполнить задачи максимально быстро, стараясь как можно больше задач исполнить параллельно. Но, есть ограничение (в нем заключается основная сложность задачи): в один момент времени Executor не может исполнять несколько разных задач с одним и тем же Task.targetId, но при этом он может исполнять много разных задач с разными Task.targetId параллельно.

Например, если мы вызовем

```
executor.executeTask({ targetId: 0, action: 'init' });
executor.executeTask({ targetId: 0, action: 'prepare' });
```

то, второй вызов кинет исключение.

При этом

```
executor.executeTask({ targetId: 0, action: 'init' });
executor.executeTask({ targetId: 1, action: 'prepare' });
```

или

```
await executor.executeTask({ targetId: 0, action: 'init' });
await executor.executeTask({ targetId: 0, action: 'prepare' });
```

отработают нормально.

При взятии задачи из очереди (вызов iterator.next() или итерация через for ... of) она автоматически удаляется из очереди, при этом существующие итераторы не инвалидируются. При этом надо учесть, что очередь может быть пополнена во время исполнения задач, а также, никто не гарантирует, что очередь конечна в принципе.

Критерий остановки исполнения функции run(): все полученные из очереди задачи выполнены и в очереди больше нету новых новых задач.

Все задачи для одного и того же Task.targetId должны быть исполнены последовательно в том порядке, в котором они находятся в очереди.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142075/discussion-on-question-by-no1imwr------promise).

Comment: @Grundy ого! А как решил?

Comment: не очень красиво, никак не дойду ответ нормальный написать с пояснениями